# Redirect from *.example.com and example.com to foo.example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

How do I redirect all users from *.example.com and example.com to foo.example.com?

My server is using Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to reroute *.example.com/xyx to foo.example.com/xyz  you can do this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://foo.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Though I should note that you might want to consider doing such domain-wide redirection via DNS configuration, if you are pointing them to a site on a different IP address.